# CodeIgniter: Language file editor?

Tags: php, mysql, user-interface, codeigniter, multilingual

I am looking to find a good way to create an http editor to manage CI language files ... ( for a custom made CMS )

I found following project but its a bit old and buggy :
http://www.mrkirkland.com/codeigniter-language-file-translator/
also it doesnt support of adding new language file and language key...

///
I am thinking of a new way for making it much easier to manage CI languages with mixing mysql and CI language files ...

there will be two tables ( lang / translations ) in the mysql table and a controller for http gui...

each time the editor finished her/his translation job her/she will click on Finish button and it will output CI language files in different languages ( but each language in a same file )

with this way We are using native CI Language system (which is fast) and managing/searching/editing of translations are much easier than directly editing CI Language files ... also its much secure ...

example :

TABLE : langs = 
lang_id ---- lang_name
1---- English
2 --- German

TABLE : translations=
key --- lang_id --- translation
hello --- 1 --- hello
hello --- 2 ---hallo

and the output will be these files

/application/language/english/global_lang.php
$lang['hello'] = 'hello';

/application/language/german/global_lang.php
$lang['hello'] = 'hallo';

what is your opinion ? does it worth to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this:

http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/codeigniter-frontend-language-files-editor

Hope this helps
:)

Answer (score 0):

For php language file editing I'm using this Firefox addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/phplangeditor/
It's easy to find untranslated strings...

[image]